# Throttle Postgres I/O for debugging purposes

Tags: postgresql

In Chromium DevTools, you can throttle the network speed, which is useful for debugging.

Is there any way to throttle the I/O speed of my Postgres server running locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no *PostgreSQL* feature to do so. You could probably patch one in, though, by adding a small sleep in PostgreSQL's buffer I/O routines.

Instead, I would simulate slow I/O at the operating system level. Particularly with a VM. Or you could use `nbd` (network block device) and a rate-limiting tool like `trickle`.

Or you could just run something else I/O heavy to contend with PostgreSQL, and possibly `ionice` PostgreSQL.

See also:

- https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/blkio-controller.txt
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48138/45708